# How can I make code run as the GUI remains open

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm writing a code to process images and i am trying to make a GUI with PySimpleGUI. I want my code to run in the background while the gui still remains open but, the code wouldn't continue unless i close the GUI then the code carries on. I tried to put the processing code before adding the "break" function but, I'm giving an error code that break is outside the loop

```
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance, ImageOps
import PIL.ImageOps
file_types = [
              ("All files (*.*)", "*.*")]

image_viewer_column=[
    [sg.Text("HANG IN THERE\n"
             "YOUR IMAGE IS PROCESSING\n"
             "WE'RE TURNING IT INTO A PRINTABLE VERSION \n"
             "NOT TOO LONG NOW")],
    [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key="-TOUT-")],
    [sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-0")],
    ]

file_list_column = [
        [sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
        [
            sg.Text("PROCESSING IMAGE"),
            sg.Button("Cancel"),
        ],
        [
            sg.Button("Close"),
        ],
    ]

layout = [
    [
       sg.Column(file_list_column),
       sg.VSeparator(),
       sg.Column(image_viewer_column),
    ]
]

window = sg.Window("Image Converter", layout)
while True:
        event, values = window.read()


image = Image.open('output.png')
inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
inverted_image.save('output.png')

break


window.close()
```

Is there anyway I can do this ? any help would be appreciated

Comment: You will need to use threads

Answer (score 3):

Statement `break` should be enclosed in `while` or `for` loop in Python, to break from loop.

Here, you can put a button in your layout to generate an event when button clicked, like `sg.Button('Convert')`, then your processing code under the event case in your while loop if the duration of processing time not too long, else you need to use thread to process it.

```py
window = sg.Window("Image Converter", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Convert':
        image = Image.open('output.png')
        inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
        inverted_image.save('output.png')

window.close()
```

Or do it before your event while loop.

```py
window = sg.Window("Image Converter", layout, finalize=True)
image = Image.open('output.png')
inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image)
inverted_image.save('output.png')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: If you do need a thread, there is a Window method, `Window.perform_long_operation()` , that can help without you needing to understand how threads work.